# jQuery change function for multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a selector form which will show or hide other form options (so you can use either past minutes or two datepicker fields):

```
$('form select[name=minutes_or_date_range]').change(function () {
    if ($('form select option:selected').val() == 'date_range') {
        $('.date_range').show();
        $('.minutes').hide();
    } else {
        $('.minutes').show();
        $('.date_range').hide();
    }
});
```

In the html, I have two forms, both with the same code (with the exception that the ids are unique):

```
<p>
  <label for="search_minutes_or_date_range">Time Selection:</label>
  <select name="minutes_or_date_range" id="search_minutes_or_date_range"> 
    <option value="minutes" selected="selected">Past Minutes</option> 
    <option value="date_range">Date Range</option> 
  </select>
</p>
<div class="minutes" >
  <p>
    <label for="search_past_minutes">Past X Minutes:</label>
    <input id="search_past_minutes" type="text" 
           value="10" name="past_minutes" class="spinner"/>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="date_range" style="display: none">
  <p>
    <label for="search_start_date">Start Date:</label>
    <input id="search_start_date" class="date_picker" 
           type="text" name="start_date" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="search_end_date">End Date:</label>
    <input id="search_end_date" class="date_picker"
           type="text" name="end_date" />
  </p>
</div>
```

So there are two occurrences of the above code with only the ids changed. How would I change the jQuery so this show hide function works for both of them independently? Currently, only the first one has any effect and it effects both occurrences of the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to find the form based on the select box that was changes, and reference your changes specifically through that form... something like...

```
$('form select[name=minutes_or_date_range]').change(function () {
    var selectBox = $(this);
    var form = $(this).parent().parent(); //depends on where your form is

    if ($(selectBox).find('option:selected').val() == 'date_range') {
        $(form).find('.date_range').show();
        $(form).find('.minutes').hide();
    } else {
        $(form).find('.minutes').show();
        $(form).find('.date_range').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This one wins over Babaks because it treats each form independently. Both helped me though.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a common CSS clss or REL attribute and use that in your jQuery selector.

```
<div id="div1" data-type="xyz">
 ...
</div>
<div id="div2" data-type="xyz">
 ...
</div>
```

And for your selector

```
$("div[data-type=xyz]").hide();
```

Comment: Already using a class though, only effects the first one it seems.

Comment: Oh actually, what is happening is the both groups of the two divs are already effected with what I have by the first occurrence of `'form select[name=minutes_or_date_range]'` but the second `'form select[name=minutes_or_date_range]'` has no effect. on any of the divs

Comment: `rel` is not a valid attribute on a `<div>`, use a data attribute instead, like `data-type="xyz"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
$('form select[name=minutes_or_date_range]').change(function () {
    if ($('form select option:selected').val() == 'date_range') {
        $('.date_range').show();
        $('.minutes').hide();
    } else {
        $('.minutes').show();
        $('.date_range').hide();
    }
});
```

you are using an absolute selector in your function, try making it relative.

```
$('form select[name=minutes_or_date_range]').change(function () {
    if ($('option:selected', $(this)).val() == 'date_range') {
        $('.date_range').show();
        $('.minutes').hide();
    } else {
        $('.minutes').show();
        $('.date_range').hide();
    }
});
```

You can also clean up the logic and calls for show/hide with toggle()

```
$('form select[name=minutes_or_date_range]').change(function () {
    $('.minutes', $(this)).toggle();
    $('.date_range', $(this)).toggle();
});
```